# MS Office Visio 2016 and 2013 Crash when saving after cut and paste

Tags: microsoft-office, crash, microsoft-visio-2013

I recently installed MS Office Visio 2016.  Today while doing my first major project in it, it seemed to be working fine.  I was doing on my work on a signle page. At one point I had a large section of a flowchart that I could reuse for another area so I marque selected it, copy and pasted.  No problem.  I then moved it where I wanted it.  Again, no problem.  Then I went to save it and it crashed.
Here is the crash report:

I am running Windows 7 64bit 32GB of memory.

```
Problem signature: 

 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name: VISIO.EXE
  Application Version:  15.0.4569.1504
  Application Timestamp:    52c5fd99
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_8296
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.19045
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56259295
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 00000000000bffc2
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8296
  Additional Information 2: 8296c5aa6c10f8fc3d26a95f13218c1c
  Additional Information 3: 99c3
  Additional Information 4: 99c303f67aeaf55ed1ca45e8fb8d4035

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I have tried this several times with smaller selections and trying to do a Save As instead of Save.  No joy.

I then ran sfc /scannow with no errors coming up.  I started Visio in safe mode and it still crashes when I try this.  Of course I tried rebooting as well.

I ran across a few boards where it said the problem is a bluetooth add-on.  I checked for this add-on (file>options>Add-Ins) and do not have it on my Visio installation.

I finally figured it must be the 2016 version itself.  I Uninstalled it completely and then install Visio 2013.  Same problem still happens in 2013 as 2016.

Finally, I decide to see what would happen if I did a new page.  So I created Page 2 in my document, the selected the area I wanted to copy from Page 1, copied, pasted it to page 2 and savied without crashing!

I have since been able to cut and paste within page 2 with the exact same items from I was getting the crash with from page 1 without issue.  If I got back to page one and try with it, it crashes again.

Finally, I deleted page 1 to see if it was just that page and crash!  Weirdest thing I have ever encountered.

I need my document to be a single page, so I want to solve this.  I also have a bunch of new work that I just got and it will require me to produce a lot of flowcharts, so I can't have this happening.

Anyone have any ideas of further troubleshooting I should try?  Thank you for your help!